# Angular component which shows a score which should update automatically

Tags: angular

I am very new to angular. I am trying to build a small app which shows scores of 3 teams on a page.

So I have an API which returns score of a team based on the ID we pass

But my confusion is how to achieve it the best way??

Do I need to create a function which calls the API in an interval

Then I thought if I add a 5 second interval, if there is multiple score changes in that 5 seconds we miss one, isnt it?

Also when due to heavy traffic or hit to the server and if one request take more than 5 second, then the next interval fires which could ends up calling the same before the previous one finishes.

So how can I make it the best way. I am working in Angular 10

Comment: Look into Server Sent Events. It's designed for such use cases.

Comment: Use websockets, so after the connection is made, the server can notify the client when the score changes.

Comment: @MichaelD Could you please elaborate that a little if you dont mind

Answer (score 1):

First of all, polling is an old way. Polling means just calling the API in interval, which is an old way. You need to build that function as socket and subscribe that score changes from your side. This is the way.

If you really impossible to change the API in socket, you can do that using any kind of javascript way, pure javascript or rxjs or whatever.

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

interval(milisec).subscribe(() => this.service.callTheAPI());
```

Comment: THats really great.. I have access into API side as well..  does that give any advantage?  I didnt understand that properly. Does that mean when any data changes, server can trigger angular??

Comment: Also the sample code you have shared is polling, isnt it?

Comment: Correct, above code is about polling. Socket way, if you use socket, you just need to socket.listen(data => {this.data = data}); and you can bind this data and that data is just count of value.

Comment: Hi.. Sorry replying little late. Are you addressing socket io in the answer??

Comment: Pure websocket or socket.io whatever, should be fine.