# Using Server Sent Event in .NET Core Web API to monitor data update in tables and Refresh angular component

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, server-sent-events

I am trying to accomplish an auto refresh on an angular component which shows scores of different teams. So when ever the score is updated I need to refresh the Score in frontend

Based on my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66904665/angular-component-which-shows-a-score-which-should-update-automatically/66904875?noredirect=1#comment118268496_66904875)  I have found server sent events are helpful for the purpose. But honestly I have got stuck with how to proceed with

Here is my update code in my controller, when which I want to refresh the score as well. Also I have a get function also to just read all the scores

```
    // GET: api/TblVottings
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TblVotting>>> GetTblVottings()
    {
        return await _context.TblVottings.ToListAsync();
    }


    // PUT: api/TblVottings/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutTblVotting(int id, TblVotting tblVotting)
    {
        if (id != tblVotting.SessionId)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(tblVotting).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!TblVottingExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }
```

I have found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36656174/954093) which give me some hint, but I didnt understand it based on my scenario..

Please suggest how to achieve that..

Comment: [signalr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: why you don't use SignalR?

Answer (score 1):

As R. Richards and Feras Salim says, we suggest you could use SignalR to handle such requirement.

SignalR simplifies adding real-time web functionality to apps. Real-time web functionality enables server-side code to push content to clients instantly.

By using SignalR, you could just write a few codes to let the server send data and call client side function to update the page in Real-time.

You could just write some logic on the server-side to monitor the database changed, like sql dependency and call the client-sdie event.

More details about how to use SignalR with angualr, you could refer to this [article](https://blexin.com/en/blog-en/real-time-applications-with-signalr-asp-net-core-and-angular/).